# How to repeat div classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I am trying to figure out how to repeat two divs that alternate. Basically, I am making a wordpress site where I want the post to alternate in the way they look. I am also using bootstrap.

So the first post with be done using this block of code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="xyz.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p>random text random text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then the second post will have the same thing but with the text and image switching sides.

How do I do this, if it is possible?

Comment: It might be more difficult than you expect..you have to edit the Wordpress theme (the way the blog generates pages to display posts).

Comment: @JCOC611 I am making my own theme and I already know how to edit the way the blog display the posts.

Comment: So you want every other row to have different style or what?

Comment: Then on the page that you want this effect on, just set a boolean variable outside of the `while ( have_posts() )` and alternate it on every iteration (i.e. `$alternatePost = !$alternatePost;`. Then use an if else to check and set the markup you want.

Comment: @JCOC611 That would actually work! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to give different classes for every other row if you just want them to have different styling. Just use the `:nth-of-type(odd)` or the `:nth-of-type(even)` selector to select every other row to be styled.

```
.row{
    /* styling */
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd){
    /* alternative styling for your every other row */
}
```

Comment: To expand on this, the selector the OP needs is `.row:nth-of-type(odd) [class*="col-"]` and you want to set the `float` property to `right`.